# python Win32 Excel is cell a range

Tags: python, vba, winapi, range

I am writing a bit of Python code to automate the manipulation of Excel spreadsheets.  The idea is to use spreadsheet templates to create daily reports.  Saw this idea working several years ago using Perl.  Anyway.

Here are the simple rules:
Sheets with the Workbook are process in the order they appear.
Within the sheets cells are process left to right, then top to bottom.
There are names defined which are single cell ranges, can contain static values or the results of queries.  Cells can contain comments which contain SQL queries to run. ...

Here is the problem, as I process the cells I need to check if the cell has an attached comment and if the cell has a name.  I am able to handle processing the attached cell comments.  But I can not figure out how to determine if a cell is within a named range.  In my case the single cell within the range.

I saw a posting the suggested this would work: 
    **cellName = ws.ActiveCell.Name.Name**
   No luck.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?
I am so close but no cigar.

Thanks for your attention to this matter.

KD

Comment: Not sure if it will be helpful, but in VBA you'd do it this way: `Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("MyRange"))`. Returns the range object if they intersect, or `Nothing` otherwise.

Comment: Yes I saw that in some postings.  That would mean I would have to loop through the name ranges in the workbook  and do the the Intersect test.  Hoping for something more elegant.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? `ActiveCell.Name` should work for you. If that produces an error, the cell itself does not have a name. And to get the actual name, you do: `ActiveCell.Name.Name` as you said. Again, this is in Excel VBA. I don't know about winapi.

Comment: ActiveCell.Name.Name tossed an error.  Oh maybe that is expected.  I will try again.

Comment: It should only toss an error if `ActiveCell` doesn't have a name.

Comment: ws.Cells(r,c).Activate()
        c  = xlApp.ActiveCell
        cellName = c.Name.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may consider doing is first building a list of all addresses of names in the worksheet, and checking the address of each cell against the list to see if it's named.

In VBA, you obtain the names collection (all the names in a workbook) this way:

```
Set ns = ActiveWorkbook.Names
```

You can determine if the names are pointed toward part of the current sheet, and a single cell, this way:

```
shname = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim SheetNamedCellAddresses(1 To wb.Names.Count) as String
i = 1
For Each n in ns:
If Split(n.Value, "!")(0) = "=" & shname  And InStr(n.Value, ":") = 0 Then
' The name Value is something like "=Sheet1!A1"
' If there is no colon, it is a single cell, not a range of cells
SheetNamedCellAddresses(i) = Split(n,"=")(1) 'Add the address to your array, remove the "="
i = i + 1
End If
Next
```

So now you have a string array containing the addresses of all the named cells in your current sheet. Move that array into a python list and you are good to go.

Comment: Note that this answer could get clunky if there are "!" and ":" symbols elsewhere in your name definitions (like, as a string inside of quotes).

Comment: Rick many thanks for your guidance.  I already was going to use a hash in python to store the names and associated values.  Rather than use the exception processing we discussed above I will step through that list.  as suggested above.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OK so it errors out if the cell does NOT have a range name.  If the cell has a range name the following bit of code returns the name: Great success!!

```
ws.Cells(r,c).Activate()
c  = xlApp.ActiveCell
cellName = c.Name.Name
```

If there is no name associated with the cell, an exception is tossed.
So even in VBA you would have to wrap this bit of code in exception code.  Sounds expensive to me to use exception processing for this call.

Comment: it does sound expensive - although using exceptions as flow control in python is the "right way", VBA isn't python of course. i'm wondering if the problem is your approach: going through and processing each and every cell individually is never a great way to do things in VBA. slooooooow spreadsheets.

Comment: i would suggest looking into [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/examples/) instead of using winapi, though i'm unsure if you can inspect comments, etc, to the granularity which you require.

Comment: I need to inspect the individual cell for comments to find SQL to run. Then look to see if the cell has a name

Comment: I need to inspect the individual cell for comments to find SQL to run. Then look to see if the cell has a name, if the cell has a name then I need to store the value in the cell as it may be used later in the processing.  Maybe as a parameter in a later SQL statement.    WIll only scan the first the first 100 by 50 anyway.   That said you may be right  Maybe all the cells that need to be visited should be named, then i could use wookbook.Names  to get the cells to be visited.

Comment: I looked at xlwings.  I cannot expect my users to have Python installed.

Comment: Understood. This might be an ignorant question, but if users may not have python installed, why is the question tagged python...? I am unfamiliar with winapi so the answer might be there.